# unable to use OneMenu inside carousel

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I wanted to use OneMenu inside a carousel to set a properties in managedBean, but its not working.

i test the OneMenu without Carousel and it work good , so i think that the problem is inside the carousel .

Any ideas as to what is going on here? plz help .

this is my xhtm page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="/template/template.xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <ui:define name="pageContent">


        <h:form id="form1">

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <p:carousel value="#{homeBean.doInstances()}" headerText="Bootstrap VM " var="vm" itemStyle="text-align:center" responsive="true">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2"  columnClasses="label,value" layout="grid" style="margin: 0 auto;" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                    <f:facet name="header"><p:graphicImage name="images/instance.jpg" /></f:facet>

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                            <h:outputText  value="name" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{vm.name}" />
                            <h:outputLabel value="ip" />
                            <h:outputLabel  value="#{vm.url}" />

                            <p:outputLabel value="Configuration" /> 


                            <p:selectOneMenu id="recepie3" value="#{bootstrapBean.recipeSelected}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One Recipie " itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bootstrapBean.selectItems}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:commandButton value="Bootstrap" ajax="false" validateClient="true" actionListener="#{bootstrapBean.bootstrapSelectedVm(vm.url)}" />

                        </p:panelGrid>


                </p:panelGrid>

                <f:facet name="footer" style="margin: 0 auto;">

                    <p:panelGrid columns="3"  columnClasses="label,value" layout="grid" style="margin: 0 auto;" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">

                        <h:outputLabel>Bootstrap All VMs :</h:outputLabel>  
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="recepie2" value="#{bootstrapBean.recipeSelected}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One Recipie " itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bootstrapBean.recipies}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:commandButton value="Bootstrap" ajax="false" validateClient="true" actionListener="#{bootstrapBean.bootstrapAllVMs()}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>

            </p:carousel> 



        </h:form>



    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Tag library initialized incorrectly, please correct it and its work.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml".....

<ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml"